# Ordering of two real numbers

Tags: real-numbers, order-theory

Is the below true for $a\in\mathbb{R},\,b\in\mathbb{R}$?
$$
(a \geq b) \iff (\forall \gamma\in\mathbb{R}: b\geq\gamma\implies a\geq\gamma)
$$
The $\implies$ direction is obvious; the $\impliedby$ direction feels weird because of the "$\forall$" quantifier.
Is "$\forall$" necessary, or can it be replaced with something weaker?

Comment: $\impliedby$ is true because you can take $\gamma=b$.

Comment: "can it be replaced with something weaker?" That depends on what you're going to _use_ the property for. You _can_ replace $\forall \gamma$ with "for $\gamma=\beta$, but that would most probably ruin whatever you wanted the equivalence for in the first place ...

Comment: Do you really not postulate that $a,b\in \Bbb R$ on the right? In that case, the right hand side is true for $b=i$, $a=42$, while the left hand side is not

Comment: @Arthur,Hagen von Eitzen: thanks, edited!

Comment: The thing is to realize "for all" $\implies$ "any example you can think of" $\implies$ "one specific example that breaks everything wide open" and now its just a matter of thinking of that one case that breaks everything wide open....  Now I can't teach you *how* to get the AHA/INSIGHT inspiration that @Mark had, but "for all" $\implies$ "any example you can think of" $\implies$ "it's true for $ \gamma = b$".   Thus we have $b\ge b \implies a \ge b$.  And as $b = b$ we know $b\ge b$ is true.  So that means $a\ge b$ is true.